# Prevent direct upload from continuing with activestorage direct upload

Tags: rails-activestorage

I want to listen to the direct-upload:start or direct-upload:initialize events and then stop the upload from happening in there. In other words, using activestorage.js DirectUpload feature, I am uploading a file on form submission using direct upload. I am listening to those events so I can check the file type and size first before allowing the upload. But no matter what I do, I cannot stop the upload from happening.

```
   $('input#user_avatar').on('direct-upload:initialize', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

I've tried that in both the direct-upload:initialize event and the direct-upload:start event. I've tried event.preventDefault(), event.stopPropagation(), event.stopImmediatePropagation(), and throwing an error. No matter what, the upload proceeds.
UNLESS... It's form submission I should be cancelling... I'll try that later.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple... do it before any of the active storage events. Put an onclick handler on the form submit button. You can get the file size prior to the upload.

```
$('#myfileinput')[0].files[0].size
```

If the size is > than you like, simply return false and the form won't submit.